How should I go about importing one module from another module, where the first module itself is importing a different module?
I have 3 relevant files here, in this directory set up:
src/operator_precedence_high_roller_bot/
    parsing/
        command_parser.py
    high_roller.py
tests/test_high_roller/
    test_handle_gamble_start.py


The contents of command_parser.py aren't super relevant, because the important part is that it needs to be imported into High_Roller. Essentially, high_roller.py is the code that calls command_parser.py when a command needs to be parsed.

high_roller.py
importing CommandParser from command_parser.py in the parsing folder
... 
from parsing.command_parser import CommandParser 
...


test_handle_gamble_start.py
import pathlib, sys, os 
ROOT_PATH = pathlib.Path(__file__).parents[2] sys.path.append(os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'src')) 
print(sys.path) 
from operator_precedence_high_roller_bot import high_roller

I figured out a couple different ways to import high_roller.py into test_handle_gamble_start.py (I verified this by replacing all of the original code with a print("here") statement, and when running test_handle_gamble_start, it just printed "here").
But when I add back the line from parsing.command_parser import CommandParser to high_roller.py, and try to run test_handle_gamble_start.py, I get the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'parsing'
So from what I can tell, there's something I need to do that I haven't done yet to show the parsing folder to test_handle_gamble_start.py. I've tried a couple different methods for this.
First, I tried to add _init_.py files in the relevant directories, and that didn't help. Then I tried to add the path to the parsing directory to sys.path in test_handle_gamble_start.py, which didn't do anything. Then I tried to add it to sys.path in high_roller.py, which didn't help either. Lastly, I tried to put operator_precedence_high_roller_bot into a package, which I don't believe did anything either.
The package is here:
https://pypi.org/project/operator-precedence-high-roller-bot/
And the github repository is here, in case I didn't elaborate on the semantics of the parsing functionality as well as I could have there is a readme:
https://github.com/carsonrobertsg2019/operator-precedence-high-roller/

I think that if in your package you remove the src folder it maybe could work. just have the operator_precedence_high_roller linstead of src/operator_precedence_high_roller. definetely maybe though.

@shamalaia that change made no difference other than making the directory cleaner, which I can't complain about. When running the test file it still can't recognize imports of high_roller.py

mmm you sure that the package is installed in the environment in which the test runs?

it's not that i'm installing a package, i'm testing my own code. I ended up fiddling with sys.path in high_roller.py to make it work

I usually always install my current project. feels easier. especially if you already packaged it.

I fixed the problem after spending some more time on it. As part of the solution I updated the file structure like so:
operator_precedence_high_roller/
    parsing/
        command_parser.py
    high_roller.py
tests/test_high_roller/
    test_handle_gamble_start.py

import pathlib
import sys
import os
ROOT_PATH = pathlib.Path(__file__).parents[1]
sys.path.append(os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, ''))
from operator_precedence_high_roller.parsing.command_parser import CommandParser

The above in high_roller.py added the project directory to path.lib essentially so that the testing python files can see the imported modules like CommandParser.
import pathlib
import sys
import os
ROOT_PATH = pathlib.Path(__file__).parents[2]
sys.path.append(os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, ''))
from operator_precedence_high_roller import high_roller

The above in test_handle_gamble_start.py does the same as the sys.path manipulation in high_roller.py, this time requiring "parents[2]" instead of "parents[1]" because the test python script is one level deeper in the directory than high_roller
